# Entity Framework 5 Guid property returning null

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I have a SQL Server 2008 database and I am using Entity Framework 5 in database first mode.

I have added a new column of type `uniqueidentifier` (guid) with allow nulls ticked, let's call the column `LinkID`.

I have regenerated the schema, however when I get an object using linq, it has a value of null even though there is a value in the table.

So if I had

Table `Stuff`:

```
ID   LinkID                       Name    Address
------------------------------------------------------------------
1    2342342-2342342-342-4-23423  stack   www.stackoverflow.com
```

If I got the row as an object `MyObject`, `MyObject.LinkID` is null rather than the value in the table.

It's a strange issue, all the the other columns return their values correctly.

I appreciate any help, even if it is help in debugging the problem further.

Thanks.

Comment: When you say "regenerated the schema", do you mean you recreated the .edmx file, or did you just run an update in the EF wizard?

Comment: In the EDMX diagram, I right-click and choose 'update model from database'. Then choose the table (which I added uniqueidentifier property too) I added the property too. The property is there in the linq class.. it is just null all the time even the table row has a value

Comment: That doesn't always seem to work with EF 5 or lower; I tend to delete the table and then re-add it (especially if it involves a foreign key, though your example doesn't).

Comment: Interesting, I have been doing that process for all my changes (can't recall if it involved a foreign key).  I might investigate upgrading to a newer version of EF?

Comment: EF6 is different enough that you need to be prepared for regressive updates if you where to update now; what I mentioned above is not always necessary, it's just what I do if a table mapping doesn't seem to be correct for whatever reason. Also: make sure you build the project after updating the .edmx file.